# Local copy of PyPI fro Python

Tags: python, pip, pypi

I need to deploy a replica of PyPI on an internal network. The idea is to have all the PyPI  packages in the local repository, avoiding to connect to the real PyPI repo all the time.

I used [bandersnatch](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bandersnatch) to mirror the files of PyPI accoring to PEP381.
Than on clients' pip I dropped /etc/pip.conf as following

```
[global]
index-url = http://www.myserver.com/repo/PyPI/web/simple
trusted-host = www.myserver.com
```

On the clients machine the command:

```
pip install -v <some packages>
```

works using the local repo. However the command

```
pip search --index http://www.myserver.com/repo/PyPI/web/simple <some packages>
```

doesn' t work and returns

```
raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
pip._vendor.requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: http://www.myserver.com/repo/PyPI/web/
```

Here are 2 questions:

1. Is it possible to enable the pip search command without install a local PyPI server such as [pypiserver](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pypiserver)?
2. Moreover, is it possible to fallback to the official PyPI server if the local pip install  commands fails (e.g. local  is not present)?

Thanks

Charlie

Comment: I think you will need a server that is able to accept and process the search request that `pip search` performs, sure. That 404 error means that endpoint does not exist for your running web server. Personally, I've used Artifactory as a local PyPi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`bandersnatch` just copies packages which is not enough to have a replica of PyPI. You need a server-side program like [pypiserver](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pypiserver), [devpi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/devpi), Artifactory, Nessus…

Answer (score 0):

I've seen devpi use /+simple/, you might need your reverse Proxy to rewrite the URL so that Artifactory can use it (/simple is requirement of repo type in Artifactory)